# sudo apt-add-repository multiverse (FAILED....!!)

Tags: kali-linux, repository

I am running Kali Linux rolling 2017.2 iso

I have done the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
```

and I received the following error message:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 95, in >module<
Sp = SoftwareProperties (options=options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/softwareproperties.py"
Line 109, in__ini__
Self.reload_sourceslist()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/softwareproperties.py"
Line 599, in reload_sourceslist
Self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
(self.id,self.codename))
Aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: Could not find a distribution template for kali/kali-rolling
```

How to fix this please? thank you

Comment: You're trying to use Kali for something it's not meant for. So, it's harder than necessary for you. If you want to use Ubuntu multiverse, **use Ubuntu**. [Kali themselves say you're using the wrong Linux distro if you want this.](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). See also this beautiful [meta post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).

Answer (score 7):

You can't add a Ubuntu repository to a Kali distribution. (Or any non-Kali repository for that matter.) Either use Ubuntu or stick with Kali's repository.

See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/ and read the section "Non-Kali Repositories", which also states,

> By adding Kali’s repository to a non-Kali OS (such as trying to add Kali to Ubuntu), this will highly increase the chance of your system not working. It may not happen straight away, but without any warning, it may break. We will not be able to offer support (and based on what we have seen over the years, most other OS will not help too).
>
> Likewise, adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.

And finally,

> If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux. More often than not, users in this case end up doing a reinstall after learning this lesson.

Answer (score 3):

On Kali Linux, `apt-add-repository` accept only `main`, `contrib` and `non-free` distribution components.

`multiverse` is a Ubuntu distribution component.

In the latest Kali release, `apt-add-repository multiverse` will print:

```
Error: 'multiverse' invalid
```

As said @roaima adding non-Kali repo will break your system.

To fix the problem in the old Kali 2017 use:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove multiverse
```