# Deleted most of dependencies

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, aptitude

I've been trying to install a certain software in my Kali Linux and used the command `aptitude` in the process. However, while using it I was prompted for something that the only thing I recall about it is acting on 17GB.

I wasn't focused so I kept responding with yes until I rebooted to find out that there is no GUI available. Only a terminal to work with. Tried to use `tasksel` to install a desktop environement but there was error. After some research, I realized that I've actually lost 17GB of data and I cannot install anything because I'm missing every dependency for any software or command I try to install.

I've added these repositories

- repo.steampowered.com/steam
- repo.skype.com/deb
- kali.download/kali

Is there any way to install all basic dependencies at once (`apt dist-upgrade` does not work either and it also displays multiple missing dependencies) or revert the system to an earlier state ? It's worth noting that I've found most of software /var/cache/apt/archives but cannot install them for the same reason .. Missing Dependencies

[Edit]

This post is almost explaining my current situation :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina
The only difference is that I have the errors showing for almost every package in my Kali (not only some software like the post), and the source of the problem is result of incorrectly using `aptitude`

This is the output of any `apt` either when trying to `upgrade` , `--fix-broken install` or `dist-upgrade` or installing a certain command : (The output is even bigger but cannot be included in this post.)

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 airgeddon : Depends: aircrack-ng but it is not installed
 altdns : Depends: python3-termcolor but it is not installed
 androguard : Depends: python3-click but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-colorama but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-ipython but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-networkx but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-pydot but it is not installed
              Recommends: python3-pyperclip but it is not installed
 android-sdk : Depends: default-jre but it is not installed
 arjun : Depends: python3-dicttoxml but it is not installed
 awscli : Depends: python3-pyasn1 but it is not installed
          Depends: python3-colorama but it is not installed
          Depends: python3-docutils but it is not installed
 beef-xss : Depends: ruby-ansi but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-async-dns but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-em-websocket (>= 0.3.6) but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-erubis but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-espeak but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-execjs but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-maxmind-db but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-mime-types but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-msfrpc-client but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-otr-activerecord but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-parseconfig but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-qr4r but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-rack (>= 1.4.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-rack-protection but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-rubydns (>= 0.7.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-rushover but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-sinatra (>= 1.4.2) but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-slack-notifier but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-sqlite3 but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-term-ansicolor but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-twitter but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-uglifier (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: ruby-zip (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: thin but it is not installed
            Recommends: geoipupdate but it is not installed
 bettercap : Depends: libnetfilter-queue1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
 brutespray : Depends: medusa but it is not installed
              Recommends: nmap but it is not installed
 changeme : Depends: python3-psycopg2 but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-pysnmp4 but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-redis but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-selenium but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-shodan but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-sqlalchemy but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-tabulate but it is not installed
 cherrytree : Depends: libfmt7 (>= 7.1.3+ds1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libgtksourceviewmm-3.0-0v5 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libxml++2.6-2v5 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installed
 commix : Depends: unicorn-magic (>= 3.12) but it is not installed
 cpp-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-10) but 11.2.0-9 is installed
 crackmapexec : Depends: python3-impacket but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-pywerview but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-aioconsole but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-lsassy but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-msgpack but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-neo4j but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-pylnk but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-pypsrp but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-requests-ntlm but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-termcolor but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-terminaltables but it is not installed
                Depends: python3-xmltodict but it is not installed
 crowbar : Depends: freerdp2-x11 but it is not installed
 dirsearch : Depends: python3-colorama but it is not installed
 dnsgen : Depends: python3-click but it is not installed
 dumpsterdiver : Depends: python3-colorama but it is not installed
                 Depends: python3-termcolor but it is not installed
 eaphammer : Depends: python3-flask-socketio but it is not installed
             Depends: python3-scapy but it is not installed
             Depends: python3-tqdm but it is not installed
             Depends: responder but it is not installed
             Depends: seclists but it is not installed
 emailharvester : Depends: python3-colorama but it is not installed
                  Depends: python3-termcolor but it is not installed
 ettercap-common : Depends: ethtool but it is not installed
                   Depends: libluajit-5.1-2 (>= 2.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libnet1 (>= 1.1.6) but it is not installed
 eyewitness : Depends: python3-selenium but it is not installed
              Depends: xvfb
 finalrecon : Depends: python3-ipwhois but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-dnslib but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-aiohttp but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-psycopg2 but it is not installed
 firebird3.0-server-core : Depends: firebird3.0-common (= 3.0.7.33374.ds4-2) but 3.0.7.33374.ds4-3 is installed
                           Depends: firebird3.0-common-doc (= 3.0.7.33374.ds4-2) but 3.0.7.33374.ds4-3 is installed
                           Recommends: firebird3.0-utils but it is not installed
 firewalk : Depends: libnet1 (>= 1.1.2.1) but it is not installed
 freeradius : Depends: libct4 (>= 0.64) but it is not installed
              Recommends: freeradius-utils but it is not installed
 freeradius-wpe : Depends: libct4 (>= 0.64) but it is not installed
 g++-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-10) but 11.2.0-9 is installed
 gcc-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-10) but 11.2.0-9 is installed
 gcc-11-base : Breaks: gcc-11-base:i386 (!= 11.2.0-9) but 11.2.0-10 is installed
 gcc-11-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-11-base (!= 11.2.0-10) but 11.2.0-9 is installed
 gnuradio : Depends: python3-click but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-click-plugins but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-mako but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-numpy but it is not installed
            Depends: python3-pyqtgraph but it is not installed
            Depends: liblog4cpp5v5 (>= 1.1.3) but it is not installed
            Recommends: python3-networkx but it is not installed
            Recommends: python3-scipy but it is not installed
 gqrx-sdr : Depends: liblog4cpp5v5 (>= 1.1.3) but it is not installed
 gr-air-modes : Depends: liblog4cpp5v5 (>= 1.1.3) but it is not installed
                Recommends: python3-numpy but it is not installed
                Recommends: python3-scipy but it is not installed
 gr-iqbal : Depends: liblog4cpp5v5 (>= 1.1.3) but it is not installed
 gr-osmosdr : Depends: liblog4cpp5v5 (>= 1.1.3) but it is not installed
              Recommends: gr-fosphor but it is not installed
 grokevt : Depends: reglookup but it is not installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libaom0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libdc1394-25 (>= 2.2.6) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libdca0 (>= 0.0.5) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libdvdnav4 (>= 4.1.3) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libfaad2 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libfluidsynth2 (>= 2.0.5) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libkate1 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libltc11 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmjpegutils-2.1-0 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmms0 (>= 0.4) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmodplug1 (>= 1:0.8.8.5) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libmplex2-2.1-0 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnice10 (>= 0.1.14) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libofa0 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libopenal1 (>= 1.14) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libopenni2-0 (>= 2.2.0.33+dfsg) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libspandsp2 (>= 0.0.6~pre18) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libvo-aacenc0 (>= 0.1.3) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libvo-amrwbenc0 (>= 0.1.3) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libwildmidi2 (>= 0.2.3) but it is not installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 (!= 1.18.5-1) but 1.18.5-1+b1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good (!= 1.18.5-1+b1) but 1.18.5-1 is installed
 gvm : Depends: xsltproc
       Recommends: greenbone-security-assistant (>= 21.4.2) but it is not installed
       Recommends: gvm-tools but it is not installed
 gvmd-common : Depends: xsltproc
 hcxtools : Depends: ieee-data but it is not installed
 hosthunter : Depends: python3-selenium but it is not installed
 hydra : Depends: libfreerdp2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1) but it is not installed
         Depends: libmemcached11 but it is not installed
         Depends: libsvn1 (>= 1.10) but it is not installed
         Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1) but it is not installed
 ibombshell : Depends: powershell but it is not installed
              Depends: python3-termcolor but it is not installed
 intel-media-va-driver : Breaks: intel-media-va-driver:i386 (!= 21.3.4+dfsg1-1) but 21.4.1+dfsg1-1 is installed
 intel-media-va-driver:i386 : Breaks: intel-media-va-driver (!= 21.4.1+dfsg1-1) but 21.3.4+dfsg1-1 is installed
 ipv6-toolkit : Depends: ieee-data but it is not installed
 ivre : Depends: python3-bottle but it is not installed
        Depends: python3-future but it is not installed
        Depends: python3-mysqldb but it is not installed
        Depends: python3-pil but it is not installed
        Depends: python3-psycopg2 but it is not installed
        Depends: python3-sqlalchemy but it is not installed
        Recommends: nmap but it is not installed
 jd-gui : Depends: default-jre but it is not installed
          Depends: jarwrapper but it is not installed
 kali-linux-arm : Depends: aircrack-ng but it is not installed
                  Depends: cewl but it is not installed
                  Depends: crunch but it is not installed
                  Depends: dnsrecon but it is not installed
                  Depends: john but it is not installed
                  Depends: medusa but it is not installed
                  Depends: mfoc but it is not installed
                  Depends: ncrack but it is not installed
                  Depends: nmap but it is not installed
                  Depends: passing-the-hash but it is not installed
                  Depends: windows-binaries but it is not installed
                  Depends: winexe but it is not installed
                  Depends: wpscan but it is not installed
                  Depends: cgpt
                  Depends: ethtool but it is not installed
                  Depends: libnfc-bin but it is not installed
                  Depends: vboot-utils
                  Depends: vboot-kernel-utils but it is not installed
 kali-linux-default : Depends: autopsy but it is not installed
                      Depends: cutycapt but it is not installed
                      Depends: dirbuster but it is not installed
                      Depends: faraday but it is not installed
                      Depends: fern-wifi-cracker but it is not installed
                      Depends: guymager but it is not installed
                      Depends: king-phisher but it is not installed
                      Depends: legion but it is not installed
                      Depends: ophcrack but it is not installed
                      Depends: ophcrack-cli but it is not installed
                      Depends: gparted but it is not installed
                      Depends: rdesktop but it is not installed
                      Depends: recordmydesktop but it is not installed
                      Depends: sqlitebrowser but it is not installed
 kali-linux-headless : Depends: aircrack-ng but it is not installed
                       Depends: arp-scan but it is not installed
                       Depends: arping but it is not installed or
                                iputils-arping
                       Depends: bulk-extractor but it is not installed
                       Depends: bully but it is not installed
                       Depends: cadaver but it is not installed
                       Depends: cewl but it is not installed
                       Depends: chntpw but it is not installed
                       Depends: creddump7 but it is not installed
                       Depends: crunch but it is not installed
                       Depends: cryptcat but it is not installed
                       Depends: davtest but it is not installed
                       Depends: dbd but it is not installed
                       Depends: dirb but it is not installed
                       Depends: dmitry but it is not installed
                       Depends: dns2tcp but it is not installed
                       Depends: dnschef but it is not installed
                       Depends: dnsenum but it is not installed
                       Depends: dnsrecon but it is not installed
                       Depends: enum4linux but it is not installed
                       Depends: exe2hexbat but it is not installed
                       Depends: ffuf but it is not installed
                       Depends: fierce but it is not installed
                       Depends: fping but it is not installed
                       Depends: gpp-decrypt but it is not installed
                       Depends: hash-identifier but it is not installed
                       Depends: hashcat but it is not installed
                       Depends: hashcat-utils but it is not installed
                       Depends: hashid but it is not installed
                       Depends: hping3 but it is not installed
                       Depends: i2c-tools but it is not installed
                       Depends: ike-scan but it is not installed
                       Depends: impacket-scripts but it is not installed
                       Depends: inetsim but it is not installed
                       Depends: iodine but it is not installed
                       Depends: john but it is not installed
                       Depends: kismet but it is not installed
                       Depends: lbd but it is not installed
                       Depends: macchanger but it is not installed
                       Depends: magicrescue but it is not installed
                       Depends: maltego but it is not installed
                       Depends: maskprocessor but it is not installed
                       Depends: masscan but it is not installed
                       Depends: mimikatz but it is not installed
                       Depends: mitmproxy but it is not installed
                       Depends: msfpc but it is not installed
                       Depends: nasm but it is not installed
                       Depends: nbtscan but it is not installed
                       Depends: ncrack but it is not installed
                       Depends: ncurses-hexedit but it is not installed
                       Depends: netdiscover but it is not installed
                       Depends: netsed but it is not installed
                       Depends: nikto but it is not installed
                       Depends: nmap but it is not installed
                       Depends: onesixtyone but it is not installed
                       Depends: passing-the-hash but it is not installed
                       Depends: patator but it is not installed
                       Depends: pdf-parser but it is not installed
                       Depends: pdfid but it is not installed
                       Depends: pipal but it is not installed
                       Depends: pixiewps but it is not installed
                       Depends: powersploit but it is not installed
                       Depends: proxytunnel but it is not installed
                       Depends: ptunnel but it is not installed
                       Depends: python3-impacket but it is not installed
```

This is `apt list --upgradable` output (again partial output):

```
afl++-doc/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 3.14c-2 all [upgradable from: 2.68c-1]
afl++/kali-rolling 3.14c-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.68c-1+b1]
amass-common/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 3.15.0-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 3.14.1-0kali1]
amass/kali-rolling 3.15.0-0kali1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.14.1-0kali1]
apache2-bin/kali-rolling 2.4.51-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.51-1]
apache2-data/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2.4.51-2 all [upgradable from: 2.4.51-1]
apache2-utils/kali-rolling 2.4.51-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.51-1]
apache2/kali-rolling 2.4.51-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.51-1]
apt/kali-rolling 2.3.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.9]
at-spi2-core/kali-rolling 2.42.0-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.0-1]
awscli/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.21.9-1 all [upgradable from: 1.20.53-1]
bash-completion/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1:2.11-5 all [upgradable from: 1:2.11-4]
bash/kali-rolling 5.1-3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.1-3+b2]
binutils-mingw-w64-i686/kali-rolling 2.37-7+9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.35.2-2+8.11+b3]
binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64/kali-rolling 2.37-7+9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.35.2-2+8.11+b3]
bsdextrautils/kali-rolling 2.37.2-4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-3]
bsdutils/kali-rolling 1:2.37.2-4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:2.37.2-3]
capstone-tool/kali-rolling 4.0.2-3+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.2-3]
cherrytree/kali-rolling 0.99.43+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.99.41+dfsg-1]
cpp-10/kali-rolling 10.3.0-12 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.3.0-11]
crackmapexec/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 5.1.7-0kali2 all [upgradable from: 5.1.7-0kali1]
cryptsetup-bin/kali-rolling 2:2.4.2-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.4.1-1]
cryptsetup-initramfs/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2:2.4.2-1 all [upgradable from: 2:2.4.1-1]
cryptsetup/kali-rolling 2:2.4.2-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.4.1-1]
dislocker/kali-rolling 0.7.3-2+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.7.3-2]
dnsmasq-base/kali-rolling 2.86-1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.85-1]
dnsmasq/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2.86-1.1 all [upgradable from: 2.85-1]
exfatprogs/kali-rolling 1.1.3-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.2-2]
exploitdb-bin-sploits/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 20211123-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 20210828-0kali1]
exploitdb-papers/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 20211117-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 20210826-0kali1]
exploitdb/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 20211118-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 20211016-0kali1]
eyewitness/kali-rolling 20211110.1-0kali1 amd64 [upgradable from: 20211018.1-0kali1]
fdisk/kali-rolling 2.37.2-4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-3]
feroxbuster/kali-rolling 2.4.0-0kali1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.3-0kali1]
file/kali-rolling 1:5.41-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:5.39-3]
firebird3.0-common-doc/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 3.0.8.33535.ds4-1 all [upgradable from: 3.0.7.33374.ds4-3]
firebird3.0-common/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 3.0.8.33535.ds4-1 all [upgradable from: 3.0.7.33374.ds4-3]
firebird3.0-server-core/kali-rolling 3.0.8.33535.ds4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.7.33374.ds4-2]
forensic-artifacts/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 20211012-1 all [upgradable from: 20201106-1]
gcc-10-base/kali-rolling 10.3.0-12 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.3.0-11]
gcc-10/kali-rolling 10.3.0-12 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.3.0-11]
gcc-11-base/kali-rolling 11.2.0-10 amd64 [upgradable from: 11.2.0-9]
gdal-data/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 3.3.3+dfsg-1 all [upgradable from: 3.3.2+dfsg-2]
gir1.2-atspi-2.0/kali-rolling 2.42.0-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.0-1]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/kali-rolling 2.34.1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.34.0-1]
gir1.2-soup-2.4/kali-rolling 2.74.1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.74.0-2]
gir1.2-vte-2.91/kali-rolling 0.66.1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.64.2-3]
gnome-desktop3-data/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 41.1-1 all [upgradable from: 41.0-1]
gnuradio-dev/kali-rolling 3.8.2.0-15 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.8.2.0-14]
gnuradio/kali-rolling 3.8.2.0-15 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.8.2.0-14]
golang-src/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2:1.17~1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:1.16~1]
gqrx-sdr/kali-rolling 2.14.4-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.14.4-1]
gr-osmosdr/kali-rolling 0.2.2-1+b6 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.2.2-1+b5]
greenbone-security-assistant-common/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 21.4.3-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 21.4.2-1]
gsettings-desktop-schemas/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 41.0-2 all [upgradable from: 41.0-1]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/kali-rolling 1.18.5-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.18.5-1]
gvm/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 21.4.3~0kali1 all [upgradable from: 21.4.2.0]
gvmd-common/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 21.4.4-0kali2 all [upgradable from: 21.4.3-1]
gvmd/kali-rolling 21.4.4-0kali2 amd64 [upgradable from: 21.4.3-1]
hcxdumptool/kali-rolling 6.2.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.5-2]
hcxtools/kali-rolling 6.2.4-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.2-1+b1]
htshells/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 0.1~git20131205-1kali2 all [upgradable from: 0.1~git20131205-1kali1]
hydra-gtk/kali-rolling 9.2-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 9.1-1+b2]
hydra/kali-rolling 9.2-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 9.1-1+b2]
intel-media-va-driver/kali-rolling 21.4.1+dfsg1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 21.3.4+dfsg1-1]
iproute2/kali-rolling 5.15.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.14.0-1]
iw/kali-rolling 5.16-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.9-3]
jd-gui/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.6.6-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 1.6.3-0kali1]
joplin/kali-rolling 2.6.2-0kali2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.5-0kali2]
jupyter-core/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 4.9.1-1 all [upgradable from: 4.8.0-1]
kali-defaults-desktop/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.5 all [upgradable from: 2021.4.2]
kali-defaults/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.5 all [upgradable from: 2021.4.2]
kali-desktop-base/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.2 all [upgradable from: 2021.4.1]
kali-legacy-wallpapers/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.0 all [upgradable from: 2021.2.1]
kali-linux-arm/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-linux-core/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-linux-default/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-linux-headless/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-themes-common/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.2 all [upgradable from: 2021.4.1]
kali-tools-802-11/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-tools-bluetooth/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-tools-gpu/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-tools-rfid/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-tools-sdr/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-tools-top10/kali-rolling 2021.4.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2021.4.3]
kali-undercover/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.0 all [upgradable from: 2021.1.2]
kali-wallpapers-2020.4/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.0 all [upgradable from: 2021.2.1]
kali-wallpapers-2021.4/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.0 all [upgradable from: 2021.2.1]
kali-wallpapers-legacy/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 2021.4.0 all [upgradable from: 2021.2.1]
kded5/kali-rolling 5.88.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.86.0-1]
kpackagetool5/kali-rolling 5.88.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.86.0-1]
kwayland-data/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 4:5.88.0-1 all [upgradable from: 4:5.86.0-1]
libaio1/kali-rolling 0.3.112-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.3.112-11]
libairspy0/kali-rolling 1.0.10-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.9-4]
libapache2-mod-php7.4/kali-rolling 7.4.21-1+deb11u1+b2 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.4.21-1+deb11u1+b1]
libapparmor1/kali-rolling 3.0.3-6 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.3-4]
libapt-pkg6.0/kali-rolling 2.3.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.9]
libatspi2.0-0/kali-rolling 2.42.0-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.0-1]
libaudit1/kali-rolling 1:3.0.6-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:3.0.6-1]
libavcodec58/kali-rolling 7:4.4.1-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.4-6+b2]
libavfilter7/kali-rolling 7:4.4.1-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.4-6+b2]
libavformat58/kali-rolling 7:4.4.1-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.4-6+b2]
libavutil56/kali-rolling 7:4.4.1-1+b1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.4-6+b2]
libb-keywords-perl/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.23-1 all [upgradable from: 1.22-1]
libbcmail-java/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.68-5 all [upgradable from: 1.68-4]
libbcpkix-java/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.68-5 all [upgradable from: 1.68-4]
libbcprov-java/kali-rolling,kali-rolling 1.68-5 all [upgradable from: 1.68-4]
libblkid1/kali-rolling 2.37.2-4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.37.2-3]
libboost-atomic1.74-dev/kali-rolling 1.74.0-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.74.0-9]
libboost-atomic1.74.0/kali-rolling 1.74.0-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.74.0-9]
libboost-chrono1.74-dev/kali-rolling 1.74.0-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.74.0-9]
libboost-chrono1.74.0/kali-rolling 1.74.0-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.74.0-9]
libboost-date-time1.74-dev/kali-rolling 1.74.0-13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.74.0-9]
```

Comment: you did not ask a question

Comment: I've added one now

Comment: Did you add a different package repository? If so please tell us in your question

Comment: @roaima using ```apt install kali-linux-default``` prints out the same output when I try to install anything : Huge list of missing dependencies of multiple software .

Comment: 3 repositories : repo.steampowered.com/steam , repo.skype.com/deb and kali.download/kali . It also prints out that 568 packages can be upgraded

Comment: Definitely a duplicate then. You've broken your installation. Unfortunately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt-add-repository multiverse (FAILED....!!)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678617/sudo-apt-add-repository-multiverse-failed)

Comment: @roaima Ended up backing up the important files and did a fresh installation . I can no longer test answers given by the community . Should I delete this post now ?

Comment: I think so, yes. Maybe +1 the two answers you've been given beforehand, to thank them for their time and effort

Comment: " You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center. "

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you removed python3 and ruby and now your desktop environment and anything else that depends on either of those two packages doesn't work.

1. Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Reinstall the default Python 3 version and the default ruby version by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-all ruby
   ```
5. You had the "default" Kali Linux desktop environment installed before you deleted package(s) that were dependencies of the default desktop environment. Reinstall the default Kali Linux desktop environment.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install -y kali-linux-default
   ```
6. Switch out of the virtual console and return to your desktop environment by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to exit from the virtual console.

Comment: If you get package management  errors when trying to run `sudo apt install -y kali-linux-default` run `sudo apt install -y kali-linux-core` instead to install only the base Kali Liniux system. Then ask a new question about how to get `sudo apt install -y kali-linux-default` to run successfully without throwing package management errors.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) is the way to do it on Ubuntu, but you can adapt it to your problem.

I will summarise here to prevent link rot:

Boot from the LiveCD (LiveUSB). Go into terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

In here we assume that you have a root directory on `/dev/sda1`

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

This prepares you for the next thing you are about to do. It is important because `/dev`, `/proc`, and `/sys` are special directories, the files that they contain are generated virtually and represent the inner workings of your system.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

This will make root directory for this terminal session to be what you have mounted above.

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt upgrade
```

Now. If this does not work, then it maybe a more serious issue. And from what you have described it just might be one. You would probably need to do something like:

```
 sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Unfortunately i do not have a list of packages that are needed for GUI to work on Kali, and i really hope that you didn't break `dpkg` itself. Nor did you [nuke X.org](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8j1n05s9-w).

Comment: Since the OP's system boots I don't see why you need anything down to and including the `chroot`. (You probably don't need `sudo| on any of the commands as it's likely the Live CD already runs as root.)

Comment: @roaima As far as i remember, LiveCD does not have a password on root, but the user is not root. However, if the user doesn't have internet access to download packages, they might still need to boot with something like a LiveCD. Difficult to know, i was just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Ok thank you for that. I've only used standalone systems such as RescueCD, which definitely does run as root

Comment: I can boot just fine and access all my files , and also able to connect to the internet using the terminal but everytime I try to download anything the output starts from "The following packages have unmet dependencies :" and it prints out a long list of packages names and their dependencies that are not installed.

Comment: @Strategist I know it is difficult to do from a non-fully-working machine, but please save that list into a text file somewhere on a USB or something, so that you can add it to your question here. Without it, we are forced to guess.

Comment: @v010dya I've added an output now , it does not include everything since the post cannot contain it but this shows my issue.