# acidently removed apt from kali linux , how to reinstall?

Tags: linux, apt, kali-linux

It may sound odd but by chance accidently I removed apt from my kali linux by the following command|:-

```
apt get autoremove apt
```

Then I tried to reinstall it with the following command:-

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.4.11_amd64.deb
```

but got the error:-

```
(Reading database ... 499865 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.4.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.4.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.2.4) breaks apt (<< 1.6~) and is installed.
  Version of apt to be configured is 1.4.11.
 libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.8.4) breaks apt (<< 1.6~) and is installed.
  Version of apt to be configured is 1.4.11.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-12) ...
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2021.4.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Please help

EDIT

just figured out I need apt version near about 1.6 to fulfill the dependency . if anyone can provide me any link to that , then I will be very thankfull

Comment: did you download the correct version of the apt that was previously installed?

Comment: no I just downloaded the latest one I found

Comment: because i dont know which version was installed

Comment: @HeysusEscobar i gues i need apt version more than 1.6 but I am not getting it on debian website

Comment: You've added a Debian repository to your Kali?

Comment: @roaima ya i though it would need debian as kali is debian base but now I downloaded the right version from kali but getting another dependency error apt depends on libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.3.11); and apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo apt-add-repository multiverse (FAILED....!!)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678617/sudo-apt-add-repository-multiverse-failed)

Comment: In particular please read my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678618/100397

Comment: @roaima I posted the solution that I figured out ,. thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks everyone for the idea , I sorted it out . And also got the lesson that never to mess things up .

I just had to download the previously installed version of apt as it was already written (<< 1.6~). And I got back apt.

```
wget http://old.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.3_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.3_amd64.deb
```

Phew . thanks everyone

Comment: After updating your system, what is your apt version?

Comment: @GAD3R had to install the correct version of the apt that was previously installed

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the right version from here http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/apt/

```
wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.3.11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i apt_2.3.11_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Preparing to unpack apt_2.3.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (2.3.11) over (1.4.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
apt depends on libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.3.11); however:
Version of libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 on system is 2.2.4.
apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 11); however:
Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 10.2.1-6.
dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-12) ...

@GAD3R this  error coming

Comment: Should i download this both dependency? but it won't create a conflict with previous versions?

Comment: how can i gwt thw apt version 1.6?